# Terminating template search

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

Suppose I have a template class like so:

```
template<typename T, const T* array>
struct NullTArrayLength{
    static constexpr size_t value = NullTArrayLength<T, array+1>::value;
};

/* Some how have a specialization that terminates on when array[0] = 0 */
```

The goal of this is to find the length of an array terminated with 0.  It would be used like so:

```
constexpr char array[] = "this is a test";
constexpr size_t length = NullTArrayLength<char,array>::value;
```

The problem is that I cannot terminate the template search.

Normally I would specialize the template to terminate the search, but I fail to see how to do so here.

So how do you specialize a template like that?

Comment: What about using a `std::array<T>`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I cannot do that because I don't want to have to type in the string length (that would defeat the point of having a magic template that gets the length of the string so I don't have to do that)

Comment: Is there a higher purpose to this?  Can you not just use sizeof(array)?

Comment: @md5i Earlier I asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892646/take-the-length-of-a-string-implicitly-in-templates) question, which no-one was really able to answer.  I am trying this avenue to solve the problem in that question

Comment: @DarthRubik Well, `constexpr size_t length = sizeof(array);` should give you the wanted result, no need for your template.

Comment: @DarthRubik `template <typename T, size_t N> constexpr size_t arr_siz(T (&)[N]) {return N;}` . Isn't this what is require, or I didn't get the question at all.

Comment: @bogdan The solution is to use [void_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687389/how-does-void-t-work)

Comment: @bogdan Your solution is actually shorter, but mine can be used to terminate any template, arbitrarily.....but yours is actually way simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your code is not terminating the template recursion, but rather the fact that `array + 1` is not a valid template non-type argument, as specified in [14.3.2] in the Standard. For C++11 and 14, such an argument has to have a specific form, `&` *id-expression*, possibly omitting the `&`. After C++14, the requirements have been relaxed and expressed in terms of the updated rules for constant expressions, but still, an argument cannot be the address of *a subobject*; this excludes any pointer arithmetic, since that's defined in terms of addresses of subobjects.

If you insist on using a solution based on class templates (not my first choice, see below), you can work around that by avoiding pointer arithmetic in the template argument; here's one way to do it, including the check to end the template recursion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template<const char* P, std::size_t I = 0, char = P[I]> struct len
{
   static constexpr std::size_t value = len<P, I + 1>::value + 1;
};

template<const char* P, std::size_t I> struct len<P, I, 0>
{
   static constexpr std::size_t value = 0;
};

constexpr char a[] = "this is a test";

int main()
{
   constexpr auto s = len<a>::value;
   std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

For clarity, I used `char` as the element type, since that's what you're looking for as far as I understand. The solution can obviously be extended to any `T` that can be the type of a non-type template parameter. For a `T` that can't be passed directly, that last template parameter can be a `bool` that receives the result of calling a `constexpr` predicate that determines the end condition.

However, a much simpler and clearer solution involves basically implementing `strlen` in a `constexpr` function; you can use such a call expression as a template argument, even in C++11, as long as it's a constant expression. For C++14, it's as simple as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

constexpr std::size_t const_len(const char* p)
{
   std::size_t i = 0;
   while(p[i] != 0) ++i;
   return i;
}

extern constexpr char a[] = "this is a test";

int main()
{
   constexpr auto s = const_len(a);
   std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

A recursive solution complying with the C++11 `constexpr` rules is equally straightforward.